# YII framework, format/indent output

Tags: php, html, yii, indentation

I just started using the Yii framework and I'm having some trouble with it. I've got my layout and views set-up, when I render my view in the controller it works fine, the output appears inside the layout and etcetera, but when I view the source nothing is indented. Is there any way I can indent the final output of my HTML so it's easier to read and find errors...

**controllers/SchedulingController.php**

```
<?PHP
class SchedulingController extends CController
{   
    public function actionStaffCalendar($calendarID)
    {
        $this->render('staff_calendar');
    }
}
```

**views/layouts/main.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Website - <?PHP echo $this->pageTitle; ?></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?PHP echo Yii::app()->params['webRoot'] . '/assets/js/jQuery.js'; ?>"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?PHP echo $content; // views/scheduling/staff_calendar.php ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**views/scheduling/staff_calendar.php**

```
staff calendar test....
```

**EDIT**
For some reason, when I view source in google chrome, all my HTML seems to be on one line, but as soon as I copy it into a text editor it is properly indented. The source appears fine in mozilla firefox.

Comment: Yes, but without knowing what your HTML looks like no one can really guess.

Comment: @Diodeus Sorry, there wasn't much to the code, I added it to the question.

Comment: OK - you're asking a question about client-side issues (HTML/CSS), yet you are showing your server-side PHP code which has nothing to do with the question. Take it out and show your HTML.

Comment: @Diodeus I'm not a dumbass, I know what's related and what's not. That's all of the HTML, there is no CSS, there's about 20 lines of code so there's really no reason to complain, you could very well just ignore the few lines of PHP. I'm sure it has something to do with the way Yii processes the HTML before outputting it, something to do with the character encoding perhaps becuase if I stick the HTML into an .html file it works fine and all the indentation shows up properly.

Comment: You're still leaving it up to us to guess what HTML is in "<?PHP echo $content; ?>"

Comment: @Diodeus This question was marked with the `Yii` tag, and I put it in the title as well, so I expected you to know how the framework works. But any ways, the value of `$content` is the contents of `views/scheduling/staff_calendar.php`. I've added a comment beside the line in the question as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible (and even not reasonable for performance reasons) to format your output HTML source because

- Yii generated html controls doesnt know how deep they are in your html tree
- You could format your own view files so that they are nested correctly withing your layout, but i would rather have it readable on source level because
- You can use i.e Google Chromes Developer Tools (Ctrl-Shift-I) to view source code as formatted

Or if you really want then something like that:

```
$html = $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model,), true);
echo formatHtml($html);
```